# Insert rows to fill gaps in year column in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id': ['A', 'A','B','C'],
        'location':['loc1', 'loc2','loc1','loc3'],
        'year_data': [2013,2015,2014,2015],
        'c': [10.5, 13.5,12.3,9.75]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

For each `groupby(['id','location'])`, I want to insert rows in the DataFrame starting from `min(year)` till 2015.

The desired output:

```
data = {'id': ['A', 'A', 'A','A','B','B','C'],
        'location':['loc1', 'loc1', 'loc1', 'loc2','loc1','loc1','loc3'],
        'year_data': [2013,2014,2015,2015,2014,2015,2015],
        'c': [10.5,10.5,10.5, 13.5,12.3,12.3,9.75]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Whats happens if there is year 2016, 2017, ... per groups ? is it removed?

Comment: the max of column ```year``` is 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lambda function with get minimal `year` from index created by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) in `range` for [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with `method='ffill'` per groups:

```
f = lambda x: x.reindex(range(x.index.min(), 2016), method='ffill')
df = data.set_index("year_data").groupby(['id','location'])['c'].apply(f).reset_index()
print (df)
  id location  year_data      c
0  A     loc1       2013  10.50
1  A     loc1       2014  10.50
2  A     loc1       2015  10.50
3  A     loc2       2015  13.50
4  B     loc1       2014  12.30
5  B     loc1       2015  12.30
6  C     loc3       2015   9.75
```